# Range of a matrix from its complete orthogonal decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, c++, matrix-factorization, eigen

In [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598471/1100107), @Gokul has shown how to get a basis of the kernel of a matrix with the help of the 'Eigen' function  `CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition`. The complete orthogonal decomposition of a matrix is related to the so-called *URV decomposition* of this matrix. I don't know this topic. I read somewhere that the URV decomposition also allows to get the image (range, or span) of the matrix. I would like to know how to use `Eigen::CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition` to get a basis of the image of a matrix.

Comment: Basically, the image of the decomposed matrix is spanned by the rows of U that correspond to non-vanishing singular values. But, as you write, if you don't know the SVD, you should seriously read it up. It's the single most important decomposition in numerical linear algebra.

Comment: @davidhigh OP is asking about URV, not SVD. It is a faster decomposition.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing. Still, I'd be interested in the use case where the higher performance of the URV decomposition really pays for the much more complex implementation in the answer below. My first choice here would always be the SVD. I just mention it because I'm not sure if this is transparent to the OP, as he was asking explicitly about the range and not about performance.

Comment: @davidhigh My underlying motivation was to get both the kernel and the range from a single shot.

Comment: Then habe a look at the SVD: it is perfectly appropriate for your task and offers much less complex coding as compared to your answer. Given the decomposition UDV^+, for the range just take the rows of U corresponding to non-vanishing singular values, and for the Kernel the rows of V corresponding to vanishing singular values. Or better read it up anywhere over the net.

Comment: @davidhigh The coding required with the two decompositions is basically the same (apart from to a final permutation for the kernel): compute the decomposition, and take the leftmost columns (not rows) of $U$ and the rightmost ones of $V$. The code below does exactly that; it looks long and complex only because C++ is a ridiculously verbose language.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni And it looks long because of the template. Generally one would do `Eigen::MatrixXd` instead of `Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it.

```cpp
template <typename Number> // e.g. double or complex
Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> image_COD(
    const Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& M) {
  Eigen::CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition<
    Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> cod(M);
  const Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Q =
    cod.householderQ();
  return Q.leftCols(cod.rank());
}
```

It is slightly slower than the QR method, but has the advantage that one can get both the kernel and the range from this decomposition. The LU method is faster but does not return orthonormal bases.